# Is "our travel from Paris to Moscow by train was very tiring." grammatically right?

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

I'm reading the book *Grammar in use* and I faced a question that puzzled me. On unit 70 (countable and uncountable 2) it ask the following:

> Which is correct?
>
> - Our **travel/journey** from Paris to Moscow by train was very tiring.

At the back of the book it is written that the correct answer is *journey* but why cannot the word "*travel*" be used here? I checked the sentence "our travel from Paris to Moscow by train was very tiring." with the Grammarly app and it did not detect any mistakes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To travel is to make a journey.

> Travelling from Paris to Moscow by train was very tiring

would be correct

---

The "activity of travelling" (travel) and "the act of travelling" (journey) are not directly interchangeable.

**Therefore the answer is** obviously bin your Grammarly app!

---

**travel** verb (MAKE JOURNEY) Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/travel)

**travel**; noun; the activity of travelling

**journey;** noun; the act of **travelling** from one place to another, especially in a vehicle: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/journey)

Comment: *Travel* can be a noun as well as a verb (go to your link and scroll down), so your "obvious" explanation doesn't hold water. The other answer (Kate Bunting) gets it right.

Comment: @ Peter Shor I  totally agree that **Kate has given a correct answer**. I am also adamant that the sentence "Travelling **from Paris to Moscow by train was very tiring"** is a correct sentence. Why I chose to use this format is because the "Posters/Postee's" example used the format **from Paris to Moscow by train was very tiring.** The use of the noun Travel; activity of travelling; would have also have meant an alteration in the format of the original statement. The "activity of travelling" and "the act of travelling" are not directly interchangeable. See CED Examples.

Answer (score 3):

A particular instance of going from A to B is a *journey.*

*Travel* between two places is the business of making journeys - "The new bridge has made travel between A and B much easier".